# C# entity framework core how to create linq query template generic function

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a simple one-to-many model: a book can have many book categories, 
Code snippet 1/2 - the model:

```
    public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<BookCategory> BookCategories { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

}
public class BookCategory
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; } 
}
```

Snippet 2/2 - The MVC controller code to save/update the book object and book category mapping data

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Book(int? id, Book book, List<int> bookCategoryIds)
    {
        id = id ?? 0;
        if (id != book.BookId)      
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var category = _context.Categories;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            // if create a new book
            if (id == 0)
            {               
                _context.Add(book);

            }
            else    // existing book
            {
                _context.Update(book);

                var bookCategories = await _context.BookCategories.Where(bc => bc.BookId == book.BookId).ToListAsync();

                if (bookCategories != null && bookCategories.Count > 0)
                {
                    _context.BookCategories.RemoveRange(bookCategories);
                }

            }

            if (bookCategoryIds.Count > 0)
            {
                var cats = await _context.Categories.ToListAsync();
                foreach (Category c in cats)
                {
                    if (bookCategoryIds.Contains(c.CategoryId))
                    {
                        _context.BookCategories.Add(new BookCategory() { BookId = book.BookId, CategoryId = c.CategoryId });
                    }
                }

            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(book);
    }
```

My question is, the application may need to handle saving/updating of many such mapping tables (BookCaterogies, UserRoles, etc.). Is it possible to create a template/generic function for all such cases?
For example:

```
public static Task SaveMappingData<T>(DbContext _context, int id, T object, T lookupTable, T mappingTable  )
{
    var lookup = _context.lookupTable;  

            // if create a new object
            if (id == 0)
            {   // dynamically find the object table
                _context.ObjectTableName.Add(object);

            }
            else    // existing object
            {
                _context.ObjectTableName.Update(object);

                var mappingDataList = await _context.mappingTable.Where(bc => bc.MappingTableId== object.objectId).ToListAsync();

                if (mappingDataList != null && mappingDataList .Count > 0)
                {
                    _context.MappingTable.RemoveRange(mappingDataList );
                }

            }
    //more code ...

}
```

So in the controller I just need to call the function and pass in the parameters like:

```
SaveMappingData(_context, id, book, bookCategoryIds, Categories, BookCategories);
```

And the function is able to locate the database table for book object, then locate the Id column and find the book object (or objects for other classes), then use the lookup table (Categories) & mapping table (BookCategories) to update  values.
So the question comes down to how to dynamically locate an object's database table and it's primary key, then use that to compose linq queries to do CRUD.

Thank you.

Comment: To asnwer your question, yes what you want to do is possible, however it requires a lot of work.  How far down the line of your architecture are you and how easy (famous last words) is it for you to go back to make changes so that you have your controller, interfaces, services, repositories etc that can take a generic model in and do the work for you?

Comment: @SimonPrice Thank you, I was actually looking for a simple solution. If it's a lot of work, I'll just stick to what I have now.

Comment: Dont be affraid of a lot of work or some re-work as it might turn out better for you in the long run